# JQuery: Checkbox how to check or uncheck all checkboxes when another checkbox is selected

Tags: jquery, checkbox

When i select/unselect selectAll checkbox I want all the other checkbox to be checked or unchecked.

There is no child or parent element

**Html Code:**

```
<div>
 <li class="input">
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectAll" value=""></input>
 </li>
 <li class="input">
  <input type="checkbox" name="practice" value=""></input>
 </li>
 <li class="input">
  <input type="checkbox" name="filename" value=""></input>
 </li>
 <li class="input">
  <input type="checkbox" name="comment" value=""></input>
 </li>
</div>
```

This is what i tried to do so far -

```
$(this).siblings('ul').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
```

and

```
$(this).parent().find('input:checkbox:first').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: I tried doing this - $(this).siblings('ul').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true); The thing is all the checkboxes are all same level, no parent and child

Comment: @Atish You should mention what you have done so far in the question, not in the comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go.

**Markup**:

```
  <div>
    <li class="input">
      <input type="checkbox" id="select-all" name="selectAll" value=""/>
    </li>
    <li class="input">
      <input type="checkbox" name="practice" value=""/>
    </li>
    <li class="input">
      <input type="checkbox" name="filename" value=""/>
    </li>
    <li class="input">
      <input type="checkbox" name="comment" value=""/>
    </li>
  </div>
```

**Code**:

```
$("#select-all").on("click", function() {
  var all = $(this);
  $('input:checkbox').each(function() {
       $(this).prop("checked", all.prop("checked"));
  });
});
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/PcMnk/148/

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <li class="input">
        <input type="checkbox" class="select-all" name="selectAll" value=""></input>
    </li>
    <li class="input">
        <input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox" name="practice" value=""></input>
    </li>
    <li class="input">
        <input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox" name="filename" value=""></input>
    </li>
    <li class="input">
        <input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox" name="comment" value=""></input>
    </li>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".select-all").on("click", function() {
    $(".item-checkbox").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

OR (if you can't assign a class for some reason)

```
$("input[name=selectAll]").on("click", function() {
    $("input:checkbox").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

OR (if you only want the checkboxes that are at a similar level in the DOM

```
$("input[name=selectAll]").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest("div").find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

Comment: ACtually i want to check all the checkboxes not just one at same level

Comment: Can you give the ones you want a class?  it will be easier to find them.  Otherwise you'd have to do a selector by name or type.

Comment: Actually i could not give class to the checkboxes as they are created on the fly and not hardcoded in html

Comment: @Atish you can add a class also if they are created on the fly...

Comment: @Atish as giammin pointed out this is very similar to other questions/answers here...your question is more about a specific set of selectors than anything.  checking or unchecking a checkbox is rather trivial.  You just have to find the right selector for the checkboxes you want to check.

Comment: @Atish I've just posted an answer that select all of them. You just need to set the `id` on the "master" (#select-all).

Comment: Thanks guys,..above solution by Saran worked! Thanks for help