# Check All/Uncheck All using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have this markup from a cakephp generated ctp file.

This Is basically a checkbox group with hobbies.

So, I want to check all/uncheck all using jquery and after all have been checked if I uncheck a single box ,check all will be removed and so if I check all individual check boxes check all box will be automatically checked.

My code:

```
<div class="checkgroup">
  <input type="checkbox" name="data[Student][hobby][]" value="checkAll" id="StudentHobbyCheckAll" />
  <label for="StudentHobbyCheckAll">Check All/Uncheck All</label>
</div>
<div class="checkgroup">
  <input type="checkbox" name="data[Student][hobby][]" value="sports" id="StudentHobbySports" />
  <label for="StudentHobbySports">Sports</label>
</div>
<div class="checkgroup">
  <input type="checkbox" name="data[Student][hobby][]" value="movies" id="StudentHobbyMovies" />
  <label for="StudentHobbyMovies">Movies</label>
</div>
<div class="checkgroup">
  <input type="checkbox" name="data[Student][hobby][]" value="netsurfing" id="StudentHobbyNetsurfing" />
  <label for="StudentHobbyNetsurfing">Netsurfing</label>
</div>
<div class="checkgroup">
  <input type="checkbox" name="data[Student][hobby][]" value="photography" id="StudentHobbyPhotography" />
  <label for="StudentHobbyPhotography">Photography</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any javascript here, although this is a current feature. Did you search before asking this question? If so on what did you encounter difficulties?

Comment: look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669005/jquery-toggle-select-all-checkboxes
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457818/in-jquery-how-do-you-check-and-uncheck-all-checkboxes-using-an-element
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569510/jquery-checkbox-how-to-check-or-uncheck-all-checkboxes-when-another-checkbox-is

Comment: @chinmaya-panigrahi check the edit, and also the updated codepen

Comment: Please guys, stop using the CakePHP tag for questions that don't even have *anything* to do with php at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/d5b01jdd/

```
var $chAll = $('#StudentHobbyCheckAll');
var $ch=$('.checkgroup input[type="checkbox"]').not($chAll);

$chAll.click(function () {
    $ch.prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});

$ch.click(function(){
    if($ch.size()==$('.checkgroup input[type="checkbox"]:checked').not($chAll).size())
        $chAll.prop('checked',true);
    else
        $chAll.prop('checked',false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/ba47992e9af6f849ba5321adaa59c12a)

```
$(function(){
  $('#StudentHobbyCheckAll').on('change', function() {
    $(this)
      .parents(':not(> :checkbox)')
      .find(':checkbox:gt(0)')
      .prop('checked', !$(this)[0].checked);
  }).change();
});
```

Comment: "so if i check all individual check boxes check all box will be automatically checked"? (although hard to notice)

Comment: @Todd ..I tried your code ..but it isn't working.The id of select all check box is 'StudentHobbyCheckAll'.how should it will work on the value of select all check box.My requirement is 1.when i celect selectall check box ,all will be selected. 2.with all boxes selected,if i uncheck a check box ,the selectAll check box have to be removed 3.if i select the rest 4 check boxes,the top one will automatically will be selected.It is hard to do because all check boxes are in a separate Div.

Comment: My requirement is 1.when i celect selectall check box ,all will be selected. 2.with all boxes selected,if i uncheck a check box ,the selectAll check box have to be removed 3.if i select the rest 4 check boxes,the top one will automatically will be selected.It is hard to do because all check boxes are in a separate Div.@dotpush